# Problems with the Intro app video for ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I am watching the Bulding an app with ember.js (the intro 30 minute video) and I am having an issue with the date function with moment.

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('date', function(date) {
    return moment(date).fromNow();
});
```

I entered that code and everything is ok when I refresh the page.  However when I go back to the index.html and change the code:

```
<h2>by {{author}} <small class="muted">({{ publishedAt}})</small></h2>
```

now when I add the date from the app.js to index.html

```
<h2>by {{author}} <small class="muted">({{date publishedAt}})</small></h2>
```

after I enter the date and reload my page I just get a blank page?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't work in both chrome or firefox.

Comment: If it helps I traced the error to "ReferenceError moment is not defined" going to try and debug that and close this if I find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are running into a js file loading order issue and thus the error `ReferenceError moment is not defined`.

I've setup the [bloggr client app](https://github.com/tildeio/bloggr-client) in a [jsbin here](http://jsbin.com/ucozax/2/edit) and the **moment** lib works correctly as far I can see. Have a look at the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ucozax/2/edit), maybe you find the difference to your code.

Hope it helps

Comment: Grr I found it, my index.html was point to the wrong file name for the moment library...